# How can I fetch a message from a channel? discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, fetch, message

I reused a snipe command code to make this fetch command but that's not really my issue here.

I'm trying to fetch a message from a channel and post it in a designated channel, for example:
Grab the message in X, and post it in Y. If that makes sense, all I have so far are:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = class FetchCommand extends BaseCommand {
  constructor() {
    super('fetch', 'fun', []);
  }

  async run(client, message, args) {
    const msg = client.snipes.get(message.channel.id);
    if (!msg) return message.channel.send('There are no messages to fetch.');
    
    const fetchEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL())
      .setDescription(msg.content)
      .setTimestamp()

    message.channel.send(fetchEmbed);
  }
}
```

Help is very appreciated!

PS: As of right now, it fetches the messages from the channel it is running the command it. If I sent a message in X channel, and run the command in X channel it would fetch the message in the X channel.
***My goal is trying to fetch a message from a channel and post it in another channel.***

Comment: Did you take a look at this question already? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64854513/discord-js-snipe-command

Comment: This is doing the opposite of what my fetch command is doing, that snipe command is fetching deleted messages, my command is fetching messages sent (not like it matters, I can reuse if I was going for that). However, that is not what I am looking for, with that snipe code it alerts whenever a message was deleted. In my case, I want to specifically fetch a message from a channel not multiple or all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the channel ID and message ID: `await message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').messages.fetch('message-id')` (async functions only)

If you just have the channel ID and want the last message that wasn't the command: `(await message.guild.channels.cache.get('channel-id').messages.fetch({ count: 2 })).first()`